# Retornar un valor de un SP de SQL Server trabajando con DATASET en VB

Tags: sql, vb.net

Buenos dias, tengo el siguiente caso, estoy trabajando con dataset en visual basic, teniendo un SP en SLQ server el cual me regresa una consulta, pero agregue un parametro para saber el numero de registros que retornar, para hacer una validacion en SQL Server me funciona bien, pero con el data set no he encontrado como recuperar la variable con el numero de registros.

Estos son los parámetros en el SP:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].registrosaprocesarpormes
    @pnIDECIA int;
    @pdfechacorte date;
    @pnrowcount int OUTPUT

    select * from dbo.movimientos where fecha = fechacorte

    --- actualizando el valor devuelto en el sp
    set @pnrowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Esta variable es la que necesito recuperar o el valor de ella en el form del proceso, espero su ayuda y agradezco su explicación.

Comment: Podrías agregar el código donde llenas de datos el `DataSet` e invocas al procedimiento  almacenado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu caso en particular no necesitas trabajar con un DataSet para solo retornar un valor, con un simple SqlCommand puedes realizar este trabajo, puedes ver un ejemplo:

```
public sub GetCount(idecia as Int32, pdfechacorte as DateTime,con as SqlConnection) as Int32
  Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("registrosaprocesarpormes", con)
  cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  md1.Parameters.Add("@pnIDECIA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idecia
  md1.Parameters.Add("@pdfechacorte", SqlDbType.Date).Value = pdfechacorte
  md1.Parameters.Add("@pnrowcount", SqlDbType.Int)
  cmd1.Parameters("@pnrowcount").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
  cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Dim result = cmd1.Parameters("@pnrowcount").Value
  cmd1.Close();
  return Convert.ToInt32(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Quisiera saber si estás de acuerdo conmigo con la pregunta que hizo el OP, no está demás que use el parámetro `@pnrowcount` debido a que la cantidad de registros va ser igual a la cantidad de elementos que tendrá el Datatable del DataSet.

Comment: En efecto si el procedimiento almacenado retorna registros el DataTable que llene el comando retornará un número de Filas usando la propiedad DataTable.Rows.Count

Comment: Gracias, por sus repuestas. (Davlio y Yefry), en resumen para validar y saber si el datatable me retorno registros con la propiedad COUNT, resuelvo lo que necesito no preguntando con el SP. Lo probare, nuevamente les agradezco

Comment: @alfredo.avmb si te ha servido alguna de las respuestas, considera darla por aceptada y/o puntuarla, es la mejor forma de agradecer. Saludos.

Comment: Gracia Patricio, disculpen pero soy nuevo en el foro, logre encontrar como darla por aceptada. Espero que la puntuacion sea aumentando el numerador. Saludos